# How to fix SSL error "CSSMERR_TP_VERIFY_ACTION_FAILED" in mongo?

Tags: mongodb, macos, ssl, openssl

I'm seeing this error message whenever I attempt to connect with SSL flags `--ssl`, `--sslAllowInvalidHostnames`, and `--sslCAFile`:

```
MongoDB shell version v4.0.10
connecting to: mongodb://<redacted>
2019-07-01T14:47:17.420-0700 D NETWORK  [js] creating new connection to:<redacted>
2019-07-01T14:47:17.687-0700 E NETWORK  [js] SSL peer certificate validation failed: Certificate trust failure: CSSMERR_TP_VERIFY_ACTION_FAILED; connection rejected
2019-07-01T14:47:17.687-0700 D -        [js] User Assertion: SSLHandshakeFailed: SSL peer certificate validation failed: Certificate trust failure: CSSMERR_TP_VERIFY_ACTION_FAILED; connection rejected src/mongo/transport/session_asio.h 242
2019-07-01T14:47:17.687-0700 D -        [js] User Assertion: InternalError: couldn't connect to server <redacted>, connection attempt failed: SSLHandshakeFailed: SSL peer certificate validation failed: Certificate trust failure: CSSMERR_TP_VERIFY_ACTION_FAILED; connection rejected src/mongo/scripting/mozjs/mongo.cpp 757
2019-07-01T14:47:17.687-0700 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server <redacted>, connection attempt failed: SSLHandshakeFailed: SSL peer certificate validation failed: Certificate trust failure: CSSMERR_TP_VERIFY_ACTION_FAILED; connection rejected :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:344:17
@(connect):2:6
2019-07-01T14:47:17.687-0700 D -        [js] User Assertion: Location12513: connect failed src/mongo/shell/shell_utils.cpp 344
2019-07-01T14:47:17.687-0700 I QUERY    [js] MozJS GC prologue heap stats -  total: 3664180 limit: 0
2019-07-01T14:47:17.689-0700 I QUERY    [js] MozJS GC epilogue heap stats -  total: 2620 limit: 0
2019-07-01T14:47:17.689-0700 I QUERY    [js] MozJS GC prologue heap stats -  total: 4916 limit: 0
2019-07-01T14:47:17.689-0700 I QUERY    [js] MozJS GC epilogue heap stats -  total: 12 limit: 0
2019-07-01T14:47:17.690-0700 D -        [main] User Assertion: Location12513: connect failed src/mongo/scripting/mozjs/proxyscope.cpp 302
exception: connect failed
```

I have verified the following:

- My SSL cert is up-to-date and confirmed to be correct
- My SSL version is 1.0.2s
- My mongo version is updated to v4.0.10
- I'm using MacOS X 10.14.5

This seems to be a very Apple related issue as the only reference about the failure message was listed in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1396762-cmsdecodercopysignerstatus?language=objc

What else can I check to fix this issue on `CSSMERR_TP_VERIFY_ACTION_FAILED`?

Expected to connect to the database with SSL cert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Was able to get past this by downgrading my mongo shell version to 3.6.8, for anyone out there suffering from the same issue, it's the v4 mongo shell on mac that's causing the problem.